# Understanding Polig-Hellman algorithm for DLP via example

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

I am trying to follow the working of an example of stated algorithm on following link (http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m5410/phexam.html).

Let the prime $p = 8101$, and a generator of $Z_{8101}$ be $a = 6$. Find $x$ so that $a^x = 7531 \mod 8101$.

The author states that $c_0,c_1$ can be either $0$ or $1$ and "$7531^{\frac{(p-1)}{2}}= 7531^{4050}= -1$ and as this $= a^{c_0\frac{(p-1)}{2}}$, we have $c_0 = 1$".

However I have calculated $6^{4500} \mod 8101$ as $4334$ which is not congruent to $-1$.

My calculations $\mod 8101$ are as follows;

$$6^3=214$$
$$6^5=-397$$
$$6^{10}=3690$$
$$6^{100}=2117$$
$$6^{1000}=1085$$
$$6^{4500}=4334$$

Where am I going wrong? Am I misunderstanding their working?

Comment: You need $6^{\color{red}{4050}}$ rather than $6^{4500}$.

Answer (score 0):

Corrections to calculations $\mod 8101$ below;

$$6^3=216$$
$$6^5=7776$$
$$6^{10}=312$$
$$6^{100}=-44$$
$$6^{1000}=3446$$
$$6^{4050}=-1$$